# Maintain First Responder while posting NSNotification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotifications, first-responder

In my app I have some background fetching occurring and once it is completed I post a notification that updates some UI values in a sidebar view (Source List).  However every time the Notification is posted the first responder status is changed to the main window.

```
  id firstResponder = [[NSApp mainWindow] firstResponder];
            DDLogCWarn(@"The Responder is %@", firstResponder);
//This can be a Tableview, nstextfield...etc.

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SBChangedAssetValueNotification object:self userInfo:nil];

    id newFirstResponder = [[NSApp mainWindow] firstResponder];
            DDLogCWarn(@"The new responder is %@", newFirstResponder);
//After the notification is called the first responder is the main window itself.
```

I would like the first responder (prior to the notification post) to be maintained so the user isn't diverted from their current task. How would I go about this?